# running a function after x seconds in python

Tags: python

I am trying to schedule to run very x seconds.
I am getting mixed up with the simple logic.

```
import schedule
import time

names = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
i = 0

def printer():
    for item in names:
        print(names[i])
        i = i+1

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(printer)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

what i am trying to get it to do is to print the name 1 then 5 seconds later print name 2 then another 5 seconds later print name 3.
i et the error saying: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment` any ideas?

Comment: What do you want `printer()` to do after it prints the last name?

Comment: Why even use this schedule library when you can just put a `sleep(5)` in the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import schedule
import time

names = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
i = 0

def printer():
    global i # here is the fix
    for item in names:
        print(names[i])
        i = i+1 # you trying to change variable in function that already been initialised out of function so you must use global before using the variable 

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(printer)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `printer` function is broken.  If you're trying to have this function print each item in `names`, get rid of `i` and just do:

```
names = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]

def printer():
    for item in names:
        print(item)
```

If you want the function itself to have a delay between each item, and you only want to run through this once, the simplest thing is to not bother with `schedule` at all and just add a `sleep` to the loop:

```
from time import sleep

names = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]

def printer():
    for item in names:
        print(item)
        sleep(5)

printer()
```

To make it even simpler, you can also get rid of `names` and `printer`:

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(1, 4):
    print(f"{i}.jpg")
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: How does this introduce the 5s pause between each print?

Comment: Man, so many things wrong with this code it's hard to keep track.  I'm not sure using `schedule` even makes sense given the problem statement tbh.

Comment: It doesn't, I feel you. But yeah, we gotta stick to the problem at hand.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Well the question is "running a function after x seconds in python". Forcing the solution to use that specific implementation detail isn't always going to help OP achieve their goal in a clear/ maintainable way. I think removing that `schedule` dependency is perfectly appropriate.